# When iterating over multiple layers of lists, do you need to synchronize only the top layer?

Tags: java, list, synchronization

I am trying to iterate over all of the instances of a given type, spanning three layers of lists. At the top layer, we have the world and its list of regions. Each region has its list of smaller areas, and each smaller area has a list of the instances I wish to modify. Before , I was using the "for each" syntax as in `for(Object o : collection)` but I did not understand synchronization enough to know how important it was. It looked like this:

```
for (Area a : World.getAreas()){
     for (Room r : a.getRooms()){
          for (Mobile m : r.getMobiles()){
          //operations performed on Mobiles
          }
     }
}
```

Now that I know I need to synchronize that all, **do I need to make synchronize statements and iterate directly through the iterators of each of the Collections themselves?** If not, how do I go about synchronizing that?

Comment: While iterating over the areas, is there any chance that another thread could modify the rooms or mobiles?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There are actually two different threads for two different things that both use that means of iteration.

Comment: Then I think you need to synchronize everything.  Unless you are certain that synchronizing the outer list guarantees the inner two lists will be thread safe.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is kind of what my question is about, and what you said kind of sounds like an answer.